# Writing variables to a text file which the user specifies

Tags: java, input, integer, output

I've been looking over my notes and been looking online but I have came up empty handed. I am trying to write code in which the user specifies the file they want to output variables to. I know I will have to use things like PrintWriter and File but can someone show me the step in the right direction.

Comment: hmmm How do you want to take "file" from user ? through console ? GUI ? anyway in console Scanner should suffice

Comment: I have a question asking which file they would like to write to. The problem is I don't know how to set it so they can type the file name in. Would I just treat the file name the user inputs as a variable?

Comment: yes netbeansuser, filename can be a variable but it will be string which you pass to FileOutputStream's constructor `FileOutputStream file=new FileOutputStream(filenamevariablefromuser)`

Answer (score 0):

See here for writing to file: [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

As for the user specifying the file, instead of hard-coding the name to be `"the-file-name.txt"`, or whatever, just ask the user where to save the file and store that in a variable, then use that variable as the file name.